# How to Include PHP script return value in Typo3?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to display the result from a PHP file inside my content element. Kindly help me on this. Typo3 version is 4.7.2

Example:

- I have a PHP file which returns the list of countries in the form of HTML select box.
- I have a content element Product info inside the content element I have placed a contact form i want to add the country list from the PHP file inside this Form

Thanks In advance

Comment: "a contact form" - TYPO3 build in FORM Object or an extension (which)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways:

- Include a php file using a [USER or USER_INT](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/Index.html) content object.
- Write your own extension (the extension "extension_builder" helps there, but you need to use an older version for T3 v4.7)
- You could write your own ViewHelper and use it from a [FLUIDTEMPLATE](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html) content object.